# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using Password:YES)

Tags: mysql, permissions, database, database-administration

root@test-2:/usr/local# mysql -u root -H 192.168.x.xxx -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/230012/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootx-x-x-x?rq=1 or http://serverfault.com/questions/353278/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y?rq=1 or one of the other 10th of questions about the same thing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-H` is an alias for `--html`, which will

> Produce HTML output.

You're looking for `-h` or `--host=`.

Comment: yes .. it's silly mistake 

Thanks a lot ..Yørn

Comment: Team ,please consider the question before making into negative [-] marks

Answer (score 0):

consider using following:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ cat ~/.my.cnf 
[client]
user=root
password=password
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

you can include `host=fqdn` as well.